# How to copy Blazor CSS Isolation file to wwwroot folder at build?

Tags: css, asp.net-core, msbuild, blazor

Currently building on a plugin system with Blazor integration, I'm referencing the RCLs' components at runtime. So far so good, I've been able to overcome most issues (routing, activation, lifetime, interop, and most basic static web assets issues thinkable).

**But now I'm running up a snag whilst trying to support Component CSS Isolation.**
Indeed, the output file `project.styles.css` or its known counterpart `project.bundle.scp.css` aren't picked up by the ASP.NET Core runner, that has understandably no idea how to reference the dev paths in the buildtime-generated `project.staticwebassets.runtime.json` file (here's a small snippet) :

```json
{
    "ContentRoots": [
        "D:\\source\\project\\wwwroot\\",
        "D:\\source\\project\\obj\\Release\\net6.0\\scopedcss\\bundle\\"
    ],
    "Root": {
        "Children": {
            "SocialGuard.YC.styles.css": {
                "Children": null,
                "Asset": {
                    "ContentRootIndex": 1,
                    "SubPath": "project.styles.css"
                },
                "Patterns": null
            }
        },
        "Asset": null,
        "Patterns": [
            {
                "ContentRootIndex": 0,
                "Pattern": "**",
                "Depth": 0
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

*Paths and project name were changed for simplicity's sake*

My first try was to figure out how to embed the file into the output .dll file, but running into a humiliating failure, and a big concern for release time NuGet-based deployment.

The big question now lies, as I've already had to compromise quite a bit on paths, **is it possible to copy over the CSS Isolation output file straight into the `wwwroot` folder, at build time?**

I'm not very knowledgeable with MSBuild, so I'm praying someone holds some kind of answer to this... ^^

Comment: I'm not familiar with this but I think you may take a try, if you copied it into `wwwroot` folder but not work, then it can't do that. And [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/css-isolation?view=aspnetcore-6.0) may help...

Comment: It's not clear to me _why_ you want this. The normal `MyComponent.razor.css`  files in a RCL are already bundled and included in the consuming project. Are you talking about another form of "CSS isolation" ?

Comment: @TinyWang Copying the file is not the problem... It's how to get to it using proper paths. 
Don't worry, I've already looked at the docs, and directly in sources over on the dotnet SDK repo. Sadly, still no cigar.

Comment: @HenkHolterman Then you didn't understand the subtilities of the question. As the RCL is loaded at runtime, as a plugin, it means build-time bundling doesn't occur. This is the core of the problem right there...

Comment: Lacking of related document about it, I'm afraid your requirement can't be realized yet......

Comment: Please clarify - you said the library is loaded at runtime, but you are asking for a "build" time solution for it? That doesn't add up - please rephrase your question and ensure all relevant information is included.

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to get my hands on the same file for different purposes.
Perhaps copying it in `wwwroot` will help you.

The [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/css-isolation?view=aspnetcore-6.0#css-isolation-bundling) states the following:

> At build time, a project bundle is created with the convention
> obj/{CONFIGURATION}/{TARGET
> FRAMEWORK}/scopedcss/projectbundle/{ASSEMBLY NAME}.bundle.scp.css,
> where the placeholders are:
>
> {CONFIGURATION}: The app's build configuration (for example, Debug,
> Release).
> {TARGET FRAMEWORK}: The target framework (for example,
> net6.0).
> {ASSEMBLY NAME}: The app's assembly name (for example,
> BlazorSample).

So we can built this exact path with [MSBuild properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/common-msbuild-project-properties?view=vs-2022) and copy the file at Visual Studio post build events.

First you can test the path with:

```
ECHO "$(ProjectDir)obj\$(Configuration)\$(TargetFramework)\scopedcss\projectbundle\$(AssemblyName).bundle.scp.css"
```

Next you may [copy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/copy) the file to `wwwroot`

```
COPY /D /Y "$(ProjectDir)obj\$(Configuration)\$(TargetFramework)\scopedcss\projectbundle\$(AssemblyName).bundle.scp.css" "$(ProjectDir)wwwroot\css\$(AssemblyName).bundle.scp.css"
```

- `$(ProjectDir)` is the path to your project folder.
- `$(Configuration)` returns either `Debug` or `Release`.
- `$(TargetFramework)` returns framework version. For example `net5.0`.
- `$(AssemblyName)` of course returns your project assembly name, which also by default is the name of your scoped css bundle file.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're looking for is a [Copy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/copy-task?view=vs-2022) build action to trigger after building and bundling the css. So in your example, you would add something like this to the end of your app's csproj file:

```cs
<Target Name="CopyCssBundles" AfterTargets="AfterBuild">
    <ItemGroup>
        // Include path to whatever file(s) you want to copy from RCL, separated by a semi-colon
        // Also works with relative paths
        // Also allows glob patterns (e.g., ...\scopedcss\**\*.* to include all files in the scopedcss directory)
        <MyCssBundles Include="{path_to_RCL_project}\obj\$(Configuration)\$(TargetFramework)\scopedcss\bundle\{RCL_assembly_name}.styles.css" />
    </ItemGroup>

    // Source files are whatever you named the above tag ("MyCssBundles" in this example)
    <Copy SourceFiles="@(MyCssBundles)" DestinationFiles="wwwroot\%(RecursiveDir)%(Filename)%(Extension)" OverwriteReadOnlyFiles="true" />
</Target>
```

`%(RecusriveDir)` will preserve the directory tree of whatever files you included based on the include pattern. If you want the files directly in `wwwroot` you can remove that or you can specify a subdirectory to place them in as well (e.g., `wwwroot\css\%(Filename)%(Extension)`). If the directory does not exist it will create it when copying.

You can also have multilpe `ItemGroup`/`Copy` pairs in the same target if you want to separate things out to be more readable.