# Blazor Server Project is NOT using the most recent css

Tags: css, caching, blazor

Localhost still uses the initial version of the file.

What can I do? (see pic)
[image: localhost remains cached]

I have tried CTRL+F5 over and over.. I have cleared all browser cache.. Cleaned & Rebuilt several times. I have even tried adding a querystring parameter to force a refresh.

LaunchSettings.json

```
{
  "profiles": {
    "https": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      },
      "dotnetRunMessages": true,
      "inspectUri": "{wsProtocol}://{url.hostname}:{url.port}/_framework/debug/ws-proxy?browser={browserInspectUri}",
      "applicationUrl": "https://localhost:7096;http://localhost:5070"
    },
    "IIS Express": {
      "commandName": "IISExpress",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      },
      "inspectUri": "{wsProtocol}://{url.hostname}:{url.port}/_framework/debug/ws-proxy?browser={browserInspectUri}",
      "nativeDebugging": true
    }
  },
  "iisSettings": {
    "windowsAuthentication": false,
    "anonymousAuthentication": true,
    "iisExpress": {
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:27354",
      "sslPort": 44398
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I saved the css file as "site1.css", changed the ref to it.. and the site hits a 404 trying to load the new file.. There has to be a setting somewhere that is causing this.. does anyone know?

Comment: may you show us the structure of your project? How do you host the balzor app, is it server or wasm blazor?

Comment: I believe the linked picture shows you the structure...  It is not wasm though. Does that help?

Comment: whats in your lunchSettings.json? do you use IIS or kestrel?

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is the default.. I am no where near ready to deploy yet :) I added it to the original question.

Comment: I think this should help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72050571/how-to-copy-blazor-css-isolation-file-to-wwwroot-folder-at-build